# Passing parameters to DAO to get filtered result in wicket model

Tags: java, wicket, dao

I'm accepting dates from a wicket form - now I want query my DAO object with the dates and get the filters result. So the question is how can I pass parameters in models ? or Can I  pass parameters in model? 
The model by default call the getObject() method - which can't take any parameter-- 
and if I use the model I can't call the other method I created (getByDates(startDate,endDate))
what is the best way to pass parameters to DAO and get show the result in front end..
eg. Dataprovider / models  etc ...

```
      final  AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<LogParsed>> listModel =  new  AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<LogParsed>>()
        {
            @Override
            public List<LogParsed> getObject() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return logParsedDao.findAll();
            }

            public List<SyslogParsed> getObject(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return logParsedDao.findByDates(startDate, endDate);
            }
        };
```

Comment: You mean: how to get the startDate, endDate in your above code from the wicket form? Can you show some of your form code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically if the dates are not part of your domain model, but rather items you need in the user interface, then you can make them part of your page, panel or form, and then reference them in your anonymous inner class:

```
class MyPage extends Page {
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public MyPage() {
        Form form = new Form("form"){ ... submit logic etc ...};
        add(form);
        form.add(new DateField("startDate", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "startDate")));
        form.add(new DateField("endDate", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "endDate")));

        IModel<List<Item>> itemsModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Item>>(){
            @Override
            protected List<Item> load() {
                return logParseDao.findByDates(startDate, endDate);
            }
        };
        add(new ListView<Item>("items", itemsModel) { ... });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - as this is more of working solution - I accept your answer :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use final class variables (attributes) or final variables wherever you're in your scope (e.g. in your constructor):

```
class MyPage {
    final myClassVariable;

    MyPage() {
        final myMethodVariable;

        IModel myModel = new Model() {
            getObject() {
                // access on myClassVariable and myMethodVariable
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Using `final` is a great way to run out of memory fast. While convenient, you really need to be sure if using the `final` modifier won't create an unwanted reference. And in your example, the `myClassVariable` doesn't need to be `final` to be referenced in an anonymous inner class.

Comment: And what is the relationship between using `final` variables and running out of memory?

Comment: Thanks a lot - I didn't use final though - but I get the idea from your answer - and solved my problem - 
:) 

no need to use final :)

Comment: Not all uses of `final` are bad necessarily. That said, whenever you use 'final' for a parameter and pass that into an anonymous inner class (e.g. a model), you bind that parameter to the instance. If this is a Hibernate entity, you keep a reference to the Hibernate session, which keeps a list of all entities that were in play with the session, which increases the memory footprint of your page, which can easily lead to no more memory. Been there, done that, trying hard not to do it again.